# keras/tensorflow broadcast for tensor multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two tensors: tensor `a` has shape `(n, 1)`, and tensor `b` has shape `(p, q)` where both `p` and `q` are small but `n` is large. I would like to get their "outer product" tensor `c` as a tensor with shape `(n, p, q)`, such that its elements are

`c[i, j, k] = a[i, 0] * b[j, k]`

How should I use tensorflow/keras broadcast or functions to achieve this without incurring a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```py
c = tf.expand_dims(a, 2) * b
```